# How to get auth token programatically in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-compute-engine

I need to access API of Compute Engine. I am able to do this through SDK but I would like to use an API.
I am trying to follow the instructions on: 
https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto
However when I try to access the API I get:

```
    com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 400 Bad Request
   {
    "error": "invalid_scope",
     "error_description": "<my private key id> is not a valid audience string."
  }
```

On this row I have provide my private key id for iapClientId:

```
   String jwt = getSignedJwt(credentials, iapClientId);
```

For Scope I am using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I am using Java as language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [these instructions](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#providing_credentials_to_your_application) which explain how to create the default credentials to make API calls by using the [environment variable](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#setting_the_environment_variable) or specify the [credentials manually](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#obtaining_and_providing_service_account_credentials_manually).

Also, you could follow [this code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-clients/google-cloud-compute#creating-an-authorized-service-object) to use the application default credentials. That document have some samples to use the Java client for Compute Engine too.